# Private GIT SSH Prompts for Password, can SSH to remote repository without password

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh

I have GIT running on a private server using SSH. Every time I pull from the remote I am prompted for a password:

```
AWS-Box:/home/git/site$ sudo git pull origin master
git@remoteserver password:
```

However I have the SSH keys set up on the server, so that I can SSH from the server to the private repository, and I am not prompted for a password:

```
AWS-Box:/home/git/site$ ssh git@remoteserver
Last login: Wed Aug 13 12:12:14 2014 from AWS-Box
[git@remoteserver ~]$
```

I checked my git remotes they are:

```
 origin ssh://git@remoteserver/~/git/site (fetch)
 origin ssh://git@remoteserver/~/git/site (push)
```

So I am using SSH not https://
I have opened the /var/log/auth.log and see the log full of this:

```
 Aug 13 12:19:11 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ubuntu(uid=1000)
 Aug 13 12:19:19 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

unsure where to go as next step. I can SSH from command line to the remote server without a password, but when performimg a GIT pull am prompted for password

Comment: Why are you `sudo`-ing `git pull`? You probably don't have the proper keys set up for the `root` account like you do for your non-`root` account...

Comment: Exactly. If you `sudo ssh git@remoteserver` you'll probably get prompted for a password too. In general I would recommend avoiding `sudo` with `git`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `sudo` for your `git pull`. Try it without `sudo` and your key should be used properly.